# is there a way to change the dispaly of a date

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I am using ChartJs library in my application for my charts. At the moment I have a chart showing 31 days of the month but due to a lot of dates, the dates are showing like this:

[image]

but I actually need them like this :

[image]

Does anyone have any idea about changing the way they are shown, thus that the date is shown below the month or the opposite.
Momentally my code looks like this:

```
const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: data.map(x => moment(x.date).format("MMM Do")),
        datasets: [{
            data: data.map(x => x.premium),
            backgroundColor: '#ffec87',
            borderColor: "#ffec87",
            borderWidth: 2,
            borderStyle: 'dotted'
        }]
    },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxis: { grid: { display: false } },
      yAxis: { grid: { borderDash: [3, 5] } }
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use multiline labels for that by providing the labbels in an array like so:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: [
      [
        "Red",
        "second line"
      ],
      [
        "Blue",
        "second line"
      ],
      [
        "Yellow",
        "second line"
      ],
      [
        "Green",
        "second line"
      ],
      [
        "Purple",
        "second line"
      ],
      [
        "Orange",
        "second line"
      ]
    ],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderWidth: 1
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderWidth: 1
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          reverse: false
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: it actually removes the data from the chart(the yellow lines). How would you fit it in my code (without removing data.map)? @LeeLenalee

Comment: Like I said make the label an array to make it multiLine, you can do this by splitting the parsed date you get from moment like so: `data.map(x => moment(x.date).format("MMM Do").split(' '))`

Comment: Got it, the label has to be an array in order to accept two values. Perfect!! Thanks a lot @LeeLenalee, keep rocking!